# SSRS date time parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to load default values in my report, like below screenshot. From to field is 'Yesterday' and to field is 'Today' or 'Now'

[image: Parameter screenshot]

I can't seem to make this to work. I want to load yesterday's date and convert time format to `dd-MMM-yyyy`

```
=CDate(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now()).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

This one works fine,

```
=CDate(Now).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler than I thought, I got it to work.

```
=CDate(Now.AddDays(-1)).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```